# Is this can be an integer $\sqrt[2z-1]{2mz+p_{n}}$?

Tags: prime-numbers

let the integers $z>2$, $m>1$ and a prime number $p_{n}\geq 3$.

is the following can be an integer for any value of $z,m$ and $p_{n}$ ?

$\sqrt[2z-1]{2mz+p_{n}}$

Comment: Did you look for examples?   I see $(z,m,p)=(3,2,161039)$ works.  Not sure what the "$n$" means.

Comment: @lulu great so the answer is yes, it can be written an integer

Answer (score -1):

Well no, because lets take z = 3, m = 2 and p = 3. Then the expression would be

$(2*2*3 + 3)^(0.2) = 15^(0.2)$

Which is clearly not an integer.

Comment: you are giving one contrary example which is not answer in any sense

Comment: I understood that the question was wether it is true for all numbers satisfying the constraints.

Comment: @NiksTopics thanks for your assitance, but the example given by lulu is enough to prove that $\sqrt[2z-1]{2mz+p_{n}}$ can be equals to an integer

Comment: I am sorry that I misunderstood the problem. I thought that the question was wether it is true for all the numbers satisfying the constraints.

Comment: @NiksTopics thank you for your contribution :)

Comment: @Niks Topics plz edit your answer